# Firefox not launching, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox

I installed firefox using the default applications installer. I have tried several times to launch it, but it starts and doesn't launch. I tried launching from terminal and it comes back as

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
         Using the fallback "C" locale.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Can someone explain this and let me know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As first, do a reboot (while this may not be neccesary it removes an possible error factor). Then open up `System Settings --> Language Support`. There select on the language tab once your preferred language like shown in the following screen-shot and click on apply system-wide.

[image]

Then so the same for the settings on the regional formats tab:

[image]

Afterwards do another reboot and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: I did this. It said that it needed to finish downloading the language package. It did. Now it's saying my account is not root when I use the sudo command

Comment: On the bright side, the "locale not supported" error is fixed

Comment: This sounds then more like a bug, or something else is greatly messed up on your system. really I'm sitting here right now trying to think of causes for this, but i can not see any relation. Did you restart after you did that language fix? But to be honest this seems more stuff for another question.

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that I am running ubuntu 16.04 for the new PINE64 sbc. They haven't 100% debugged everything with it yet. I'll just use midori for now. Thanks though